# Ember-table shows index on the header

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

I am using `ember-table` but have a weird behavior. It automatically adds index next to my header title.

[image]

But after I click one of the header to sort the table, the index will disappear as I want. How do I get rid of the index in the first place. Plus, without the sorting function, the table was normal.

After I click anyone of the header to sort the column, the index will go away.

[image]

Here is my sort object

```js
sorts = [
  { valuePath: 'username' },
  { valuePath: 'total_assignment_count' },
  { valuePath: 'accepted_assignment_count' },
  { valuePath: 'accepted_rate' },
  { valuePath: 'acl_name' },
  { valuePath: 'repo_name'}
];
```

template

```html
<EmberTable as |t|>
  <t.head
    @columns={{this.tableColumns}}
    @sorts={{this.sorts}}
    @onUpdateSorts={{action (mut this.sorts)}}
  />
  <t.body @rows={{this.tableData}} />
</EmberTable>
```

Comment: what does `tableColumns` look like? and `tableData`, too?

Comment: I fixed the issue, use only one sorting key do the trick. `sorts = [  { valuePath: 'username' } ];`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker solved the problem themseves and didn't post an answer. I would retract my vote to close if an answer is posted tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Use only one sorting key.

```
sorts = [  { valuePath: 'username' } ];
```

Moreover, if you specify more than 1 key, then `ember-table` will help sort the table by the sequence.

EX:

```
sorts = [
  { valuePath: 'username' },
  { valuePath: 'score' },
];
```

The table will sort `username` first and then `score`